# As a Reddit moderator, how do I compel each text post to contain this same Q & A format?

Tags: reddit

1. How can I obligate this format of questions and answers in each text post (on my SubReddit)? Posters shall answer EACH numbered question, which posters can't change.
2. How can AutoModerator remove any post that changed, or that failed to answer ANY ONE, of these default questions?

---

##### TEXT FOR QUESTION 1

#### TEXT FOR QUESTION 2

#### TEXT FOR QUESTION 3

##### SUBTEXT FOR QUESTION 3.1.

##### SUBTEXT FOR QUESTION 3.2.